# How do you kill a player standing on a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Parkour Map and I need to know how to execute
`/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass 0 /kill @p[c=1]` in 1.13.
It doesn't work for me, because this code was used in version 1.9 or thereabouts. 
I'm  playing on PC.

How do you do execute this command in 1.13?

Answer (score 3):

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:grass run kill @s
```

This selects all players, individually checks each player to see if the block beneath them is grass, then kills off the player if it is.

A good place to look up what you can do with the execute command is on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute)

Answer (score 0):

how to kill someone when standing on a block in minecraft pc 1.13

```
execute as @a[distance=..1] run kill @s
```

use that command in pc it works in 1.13

Comment: Doesn’t this just find a player within a distance of 1 from the command block?