# How to teleport someone somewhere else when they stand at a specific location, with the command block somewhere out of sight

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m not sure how to words this, but this is what I want to is:
Player stands on a purple block and is teleported to a red block without touching the command block
Different wording- when you walk into a certain place you are teleported, but the command block is far away and out of sight.
Like, if they go into a area then they will be teleported.

Comment: So, you want the command block to be triggered in a certain area, but it is far away, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you kill a player standing on a specific block?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341263/how-do-you-kill-a-player-standing-on-a-specific-block)

Comment: Do you want to detect by block type, or location?

Answer (score 3):

1. Give yourself a command block.

```
/give @s command_block
```

2. To avoid having your chat being over run by messages, set the game rule `CommandBlockOutput` to false.

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

3. Go to the purple block and stand on top of it. Once you are standing on the block, press <kbd>F3</kbd> *(<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> on some keyboards)* to find your coordinates. **These will be referred to as x1, y1, and z1**

*(Optional) Type your coordinates into chat to help you remember them.*

4. Now, go to the red block, and repeat step 3. **These will be referred to as x2, y2, and z2**.
5. Now, go to where you want the command block to be placed, and place it there.
6. Right-click your mouse on it, and change `Impulse` to `Repeat`.
7. Now change `Needs Redstone` to `Always Active`.
8. 

#### 1.13+

Enter the text:

```
tp @a[x=X1, y=Y1, z=Z1, distance=..0.5] X2 Y2 Z2
```

into the area that says `Console Command`.

#### 1.12.2-

Enter the text:

```
tp @a[x=X1,y=Y1,z=Z1,r=1] X2 Y2 Z2
```

into the area that says `Console Command`.

9. Hit the button labeled  `Done`.

Comment: I put the command in the command block but it didn’t work, I’m in version 1.16.5, does this matter? I’m pretty sure that I put the command in right. Thanks for the advice, I’m not very good with command blocks. :)

Comment: This really looks like it will work, perhaps you need to change the viewing distance. @Doot

Comment: Is this answer automatic? You can post 2 with one you can use buttons for and not.

Comment: Didn’t see this until now I’ll try those ideas :) also does the command block and the place where I do the teleporting need to be in render distance? I do have my render distance very low because my computer is laggy

Comment: I didn’t understand what you meant by “is this answer automatic? You can post 2 with one you can use buttons for and not.” Are you asking if what I responded with to your answer or is it something to do with the command block

Comment: I haven’t used this website before, so I don’t know how to do stuff. Thanks for helping with my redstone :)

Comment: Also my teleported area (both where I’m teleported to and where I’m teleported from) are under water but the command block is on land about 100 blocks away

Comment: That doesn't affect anything. Did you change the variables to the coordinates?

Comment: @Doot besides for question phrasing (it's a bit hard for me at least to understand the question) you've done everything else right, I'm not exactly sure what he means but don't worry!

Comment: It's not Shift + F3 but simply just "F3"